# Why are images not sent when submitting axois post?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My images are not being sent during submit post request. Here is my code:

```
let url =  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/post_ads';
        let headers =  {
          'username': '', 
          'password': '', 
          'Authorization': '', 
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        };
        
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('is_new_item', is_new);
         image.forEach(file=>{
          data.append("files",file)
          
        })



    
    
        let submit_ads = axios.post(url,data,{headers:headers}).then((res)=>{
          console.log(res)
        })
```

Where am I doing a mistake? Here is screenshot1 where it's saying Unprocessable Entity.
See screenshot2 where it's saying `"Expected UploadFile, received: <class 'str'>"` which means I am uploading image file and it's getting string but I don't know why?

[image]

[image]

I am using fast api and my database column name **image_url** so I aslo tried this:

```
image.forEach(file=>{
              data.append("image_url",file)
              
            })
```

but getting error fields required when submitting post request.

Comment: Can you please try setting name property to your image files ?

Comment: its's `files` name.  I am using fast api.

Comment: my database column name image_url  and also tried with this name but getting fields required error

Comment: No, what i meant is, you are looping through all images with forEach and appending every image to a formData. Probably the `file` is an object. Append name property to file. For ex: `file.name = 'blabla'`

Answer (score 0):

The following error 422 is only for validation rules and as per the error, you must need to check the back-end side validation for image value.

I think the error came from the back-end server of validation.

Possible Reasons behind the errors :

1. Image size validation
2. Image type validation
3. form key name validation like check the front end and back end for parameter names are same or not.

Comment: the error only  occurring when I am submitting post request from reacjs app and I also tested my api with postman and there was no error.

Comment: debug the request before the validation and check everything is ok or not inside the request data. From there you will get the actual reason of 422 error.

Comment: The error I am getting `"field required"` for image fields which means I am doing mistake in my post request and image not sending to server

Comment: Yes exactly you need to print request body inside api function for check request payload.

Comment: I did and already said my image files not sending to server